# Cython cdef statement

Tags: python, cython

I am working through some code and have come across this:

```py
cdef:
    float [::1] embed, feats, doc_embed, mention_embed, best_score
    float [:, ::1] s_inp, p_inp
```

Could someone kindly explain what is being declared here? I am not quite sure if this is a python Slice or a C language specific thing. Please let me know if I can provide any other information.

Comment: Those are actually declarations for cython-specific [typed memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html).

Comment: Oh, cool! Thanks CodeSurgeon! I am quite the stereotypical millennial who can only really code in python :/

Answer (score 3):

These are definitions for 1D and 2D [typed memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html). You can think of them as being numpy arrays. It's generally preferred to use memoryviews these days instead of numpy arrays directly because using memoryviews lets cython generate more efficient code.